# How to connect to peers/store into account/accountdata tables when running stellar-core on windows?

Tags: stellar-core, windows, peers, postgres

I set up stellar-core on windows following the windows installation instructions. I was able to build the solution successfully and am able to run "stellar-core" from the command line. I've set up a postgres DB named "Core" and ran "stellar-core --newdb" to install the schema.

"stellar-core" runs continuously while in either debug or debugnopostgres modes and creates/updates records in the scphistory and scpquorums tables in either a postgres or sqlite database, but it looks like it can't maintain any peer connections.

I'm looking to be able to access the accounts and accountdata tables, however it doesn't appear that stellar-core is storing any information from the ledgers into these tables, and when on the release version it crashes. I've attached 2 log files and am looking for help or suggestions from anyone who has run into similar issues or has been able to set up stellar-core node on windows.

I've tried using a variety of config files including the default test-net version, all have the same issue.

I'm not looking to set up a validator node, just a watcher.

[Debug Log-File](https://pastebin.com/43sXA3SS)

[Release Log-File](https://pastebin.com/taw0x0Mh)

[Config](https://pastebin.com/28iDpuYU)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up scratching everything, recloning, and starting over from the installation guide. I believe my issue was in the configuration file. I tried several edits and reruns and honestly I'm not too sure what change fixed it.

Below is the config I used for a working LIVE instance.

[LIVE CONFIG](https://pastebin.com/SDLr6Yt5)

My testnet version is identical except the history urls and node names are pulled from the given testnet example config.